# VueJS - Object in VUEX store not the same between development server and production build

Tags: vue.js

I have an object in a vue component with about 8 keys. It forms part of the data object.

The interesting thing is when I use - `npm serve` everything works 100% and the whole dictionary can be observerved in the `VUEX store` after a mutation.

If I then use `npm build` on the exact unmodified code the json object is not the same in the `VUEX Store` and is missing some of the keys after a mutation.

This is so weird. I have searched for a day and cannot find any reference to this.

Comment: Can you provide the json object in the question?

Comment: Did you find the solution?